# Sequelize error "Unknown column in 'field list'" during CREATE for One-to-Many Association

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have been using the following tutorial to **learn how to implement one-to-many relationship in Sequelize** where a `Tutorial` has many `Comment` and `Comment` belongs to a `Tutorial`: https://www.bezkoder.com/sequelize-associate-one-to-many/

While I have the code modeling what is documented for setting up the relationship between the two models, I receive the following error during creating the `Comment` model:

> Unknown column 'tutorialId' in 'field list'

Additionally, I receive the following SQL output:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`,`name`,`text`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`tutorialId`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?);
```

**app.js**

```
const tutorialsRouter = require('./routes/api/tutorials');
const commentsRouter  = require('./routes/api/comments');

app.use('/api/tutorials', tutorialsRouter);
tutorialsRouter.use('/:tutorialId/comments', commentsRouter);
```

**/models/index.js**

```
db.tutorials = require("./tutorial.model")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.comments  = require("./comment.model")(sequelize, Sequelize);

db.tutorials.hasMany(db.comments, { as: "comments" });
db.comments.belongsTo(db.tutorials, {
  foreignKey: "tutorialId",
  as: "tutorial",
});
```

**/models/comment.model.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  
  const Comment = sequelize.define('comment', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    text: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  });

  return Comment;
}
```

**/routes/comments.js**

```
const comments = require('../../controllers/comments.controller');
const router = require('express').Router({ mergeParams: true });

router.post('/', comments.create);

module.exports = router;
```

**/controllers/comments.controller.js**

```
const db = require('../models');
const Comment = db.comments;

exports.create = (req, res) => {
  ...
  Comment.create({
    name:       req.body.name,
    text:       req.body.text,
    tutorialId: req.params.tutorialId,
  })
    .then( ... )
    .catch( ... );
}
```

Then in Postman I receive a 500 (of the error message above) when issuing the request:
`POST localhost:3000/api/tutorials/1/comments`

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "text": "Lorem ipsum..."
}
```

I don't think I should have to define a `tutorialId` field on the `Comment` model. Grr...

This may be very obvious to some of you, but it's tripping me up trying to learn. **Any help is very much appreciated. :)**

Comment: You might be running into trouble as a result of the aliases, which are optional.  What happens if you just have `db.tutorials.hasMany(db.comments)` and `db.comments.belongsTo(db.tutorials)`, without the `options` parameters?  It should just use the defaults, which are similar to what you have for `as` and `foreignKey`....  Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you're having is a result of using aliases via the `as` property.  See the docs for [belongsTo](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-belongsTo) and [hasMany](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-hasMany).  Here's a code sample that performs the inserts without the error.

```
let {
        Sequelize,
        DataTypes,
    } = require('sequelize')

async function run () {
    let sequelize = new Sequelize('dbname', 'username', 'password', {
            host:       'localhost',
            port:       5555,
            dialect:    'postgres',
            logging:    console.log
        })

    let Comment = sequelize.define('comment', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        text: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
    })

    let Tutorial = sequelize.define('tutorial', {
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        content: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        }
    })

    Tutorial.hasMany(Comment)
    Comment.belongsTo(Tutorial)

    // This just recreates the tables in the database.
    //  You would really only want to use a force sync
    //  in a development environment, since it will destroy
    //  all of the data....
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true })

    let tutorial = await Tutorial.create({
        title:      'Tutorial',
        content:    'Hmm....'
    })

    let comment = await Comment.create({
        name:       'Comment',
        text:       'Something, something....',
        tutorialId: tutorial.id,
    })

    await sequelize.close()
}

run()
```

**Edit**

This is just an edit to my original answer above.  The OP Tom Doe discovered that the issue was being caused by a mismatch between the definitions of the tables in the database and the models defined via `sequelize` (see comments below).  As we discovered, one way to troubleshoot the mismatch is to force sync a new version of the database, and then compare the new version of the database with the original version.  There may be differences in the definitions of the columns or the contraints.  Force syncing the database can be done via the command

```
await sequelize.sync({ force: true})
```

*Important Note*:  The above statement will overwrite the existing database and all of its data.  See [the docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#model-synchronization) for more information.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me :(

I pushed up the repo if that makes it easier: https://github.com/benbabics/express-sequelize

Comment: @TomDoe That's great, thanks:)  I cloned your repo and ran it against a mysql database on my local machine, and I was able to insert a tutorial and a comment for the tutorial on by sending http requests to your website.  I created a public `gist` that has the output results of the experiment, found [here](https://gist.github.com/andrewgregorywright/4cc24ebe8e971e5ef833f15a7042bef0).  It's possible that the existing database structure you have is different from the one that was created on my local machine by your code.  Check out the `gist` in the link and let me know if this helps!

Comment: @TomDoe I almost forgot to mention, I submitted a pull request to your repo on github that has the code that I used to submit the `http` requests for creating a new tutorial and an associated comment.  Everything seemed to work fine on my end....

Comment: That's what it was. After dropping and re-syncing the db it all worked. Thank you!!

Comment: @TomDoe That's great Tom!  I've edited my answer to reflect what you found in the comments:)

Comment: A hundred upvotes for you if I could. Thanks again! :)